# Limiting the MySQL error log file size

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm using MySQL enterprise edition for large database. When running several queries following error message logged into error log file.

> Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since `BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT`. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that     inserts into an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly.

This causes increased disk usage, and I need to control this situation.

Is there any way to rotate the error logs (as it is done for access logs)? Or is there a way to control the maximum file size for the error log?

Summary: 
When running several queries, this error message is logged to the error log. Therefore our disk is filling up. I need to limit the error log size or apply log rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget reducing the size of the error logs, [**fix the problem**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-formats.html). Change your `binlog_format` to `mixed` (preferred) or `row`.

Comment: I need to control error log. Bin log is OK. But error log size cannot be limit.